# How to dynamically configure the WebLogicCluster property outside of web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic, web.xml, cluster-computing

I have a web application deployed as war file in weblogic 10.3.3. Now I want to make this application clusterable. For this I'm using the `HttpClusterServlet` from Weblogic as a load balancer. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/cluster/setup.html#wp684345) I can put this servlet configuration into the web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HttpClusterServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>weblogic.servlet.proxy.HttpClusterServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>WebLogicCluster</param-name>
      <param-value>server-1:7122|server-1:7123</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

The problem is that this configuration is hard wired at build time and can't be reconfigured at runtime. For instance I would like to be able to add 5 more servers dynamically. I had several ideas to solve that problem:

1. Extend the `weblogic.servlet.proxy.HttpClusterServlet` with an own servlet implentation. This is not possible, the class is final.
2. Use a servlet filter to reconfigure the servlet. The servlet is not accessible anymore through [ServletContext().getServlet(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServlet%28java.lang.String%29) since Java Servlet API 2.1, with no direct replacement.
3. Reflection might be an option, but I couldn't figure out a reliable way to access the configuration

All of my attempts to reconfigure this init-param externally failed so far. I'm open to any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This might help [How to externalize web.xml servlet init-param? Spring DelegatingFilterProxy for Servlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2845690/99795) Even if your not using Spring it wouldn't be too hard to port that servlet to another IoC container.

Comment: That looks like a quite interesting approach... Let's see if it works in this case (without Spring)